# using plsql table in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I am using plsql in a oracle database 9i
I have a stored procedure,
With an in parameter of "table of number" that is called numbers.
I now want to select all rows from a table where a column named: ID is equal to a number inside "numbers"
Just like I can do `select * from table name where Id in (!,!,!,...)`
Thanks for the help.

Update :
Just to clear up,
I have a user defined type named numbers,
Number is defined: table of number.
So in the procedure decleration I have 
"P_array in numbers"
I need to `select * from a table where Id is found in p_array`

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
SQL> create type numbers as table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table foo (id number) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo select rownum from dual connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from foo;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10

10 rows selected.

SQL> create procedure testnum(p_num in numbers)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    for r_row in (select id
  5                    from foo f
  6                   where f.id in (select /*+ cardinality(t, 10) */ column_value
  7                                    from table(p_num) t))
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(r_row.id);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serverout  on
SQL> exec testnum(numbers(2, 6, 9));
2
6
9
```

the cardinality hint is used to tell oracle roughly how many elements are in your table. without it, Oracle will assume ~8k rows which may be too high and cause unwanted full scans in the plans.

you can do a direct join too if you prefer.

```
for r_row in (select /*+ cardinality(t, 10) */ f.id
                from foo f
                     inner join table(p_num) t
                             on t.column_value = f.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following :-

```
select * from tableName where id in (select c.column_value from table(cast(p_array as numbers)) c);
```

where numbers is table of number

Comment: This compiles but I am getting an ora 22905 when excecuting

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM A_TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT SAVED_NUMBERs FROM TABLE_NUMBER);
```

Do you mean this?

Comment: I tried "select * from atable where Id in (select saved_numbers from numbers).          I got ora 04044 error

Comment: Scratch that, I tried "select * from tableName where id  in (select saved_numbers from myArrayName)".   I got a 00942 ora error

Comment: Wait so you have an array which contains all the numbers? If that's the case try:  SELECT * FROM <YOURTABLENAMEHERE> WHERE ID IN <YOURARRAYNAMEHERE>;

Comment: I have a table type that is named numbers, defined : "table of number". I have a numbers variable. And using it with the obvious syntax you also suggested doesent work, I get "ora 00932 expected NUMBER got DB.NUmbers

Comment: Could you update your original post with the tables and columns? It's pretty unclear to me.